# svg, d3 "Y" scale how to set background width. Vertical svg d3 slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I have a Y scale:

```
d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([1, 10])
    .range([15, 0])
```

When it is rendered it outputs html like

```
<rect class="background" style="visibility: hidden; cursor: crosshair;" height="15" width="15" x="0">
```

Then I can go and change height of that background rectangle like this:

```
slider.select(".background")
    .attr("height", 7);
```

And that change is applied, however when i try to do the same with width:

```
slider.select(".background")
    .attr("width", 7);
```

The rendered html output does not change - it still remains 15 and not 7.

How can I change width, given that I want to keep length of the scale the same, that is I dont want to change value here `range([15, 0])` The reason I don't want to have such width is that I am making vertical slider and that background sheet is too wide and I don't need it to be 15x15.

---

---

Edit. This is actually vertical svg d3 slider. This is how I render it:

```
var slider=null, sliderActive = false;

var margin = {top: 200, right: 50, bottom: 200, left: 50},
    height = 150;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([3, 500])
    .range([height, 0])
    .clamp(true);

var brush = d3.svg.brush();

/*
 * Brush states:
 * "-1" - brush is not not moved or clicked
 *  "1" - brush is clicked
 *  "2" - brush is moved
 */
var brushState = -1;

    var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var slider = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "slider")
    .call(brush);

var handle = slider.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "handle")
    //.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 20 + ", 0 )")
    .attr("r", 9);

    var Sample = {    
      initialize: function(settings) {

        brush.x(x)
        .extent([0, 0])
        .on("brush", brushMoved);

        brush
        .on("brushstart", brushClicked);

        brush
        .on("brushend", brushReleased);

        svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        //.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 20 + ", 0 )")
        .call(d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("left")
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + "%"; })
        .ticks(6)
        .tickSize(0)
        .tickPadding(12))
        .select(".domain")
        .select(function() { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); });

        slider.selectAll(".extent,.resize")
        .remove();

        slider.select(".background")
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("width", 20);

        slider
        .call(brush.event)
        .transition() // gratuitous intro!
        .duration(750)
        .call(brush.extent([100, 100]))
        .call(brush.event);

      },

    };

    function brushClicked() {
        brushState = 1;
    }

    function brushMoved() {
          brushState = 2;
          var value = brush.extent()[1];

          if (d3.event.sourceEvent) { // not a programmatic event
            value = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[1]);
            brush.extent([value, value]);
          }

          handle.attr("cy", x(value));
    }

    function brushReleased() {
        brushState = -1;
    }
```

Notice line:

```
        slider.select(".background")
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("width", 20);
```

It sets height, yes, but not width.

Code used as an example and reference is taken from: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6452972

Comment: How are you rendering that rectangle in the first place?

Comment: The brush component is resetting width and height internally. You need to add your own rectangle if you want to control it exclusively.